# pdf.js: PDF renders incorrectly after Chrome update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js in my web application and it works fine until I updated chrome to Version 30.0.1599.69 m this morning.
The PDF is rendered with wrong character. Zooming in or out may correct the character but it doesn't work to all document. Different document may be 'corrected' with different zoom scale.
Sometime zooming doesn't fix the problem.

Does anyone facing the same problem? Any solution?

Screen capture:

[image]

Comment: hi may be the latest chrome is incompatible with the pdf.js plugin just make check if it works in firefox....

Comment: It works fine in FF.
Yes, it seems like the latest chrome is incompatible with pdf.js
I am looking forward for the solution as users are restricted to use Chrome only.

Comment: Can you open an issue at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/isssues/new, and include (a link to) (a fragment of) the PDF file + browser version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution is to fix users' chrome version to version 29. This is the most practical solution in our case for the time being.